# AOSP vanilla Android port to non-nexus device - writing device trees and kernels

Tags: android, customization, android-source, porting

Greetings Developers,

I am new to ROM building/porting process. I want to install Vanilla Android(AOSP) on my note-4, so after querying Google number of times, I came across official Android development guide on official Android website: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

I have downloaded the Android source locally and was following various Guides and tutorials from XDA-University & forums only for the development process. http://xda-university.com/as-a-devel...ng-source-code

I discovered that for downloading/configuring the build for a specific device(trltexx), we need to create a localmanifest file that contains device tree, vendor and kernel configuration links for repo syncing.

Now, I want your expertise to guide me forward from this point.

**Questions being**:

1. Can I use CM or other projects (eg. AICP etc.) device configurations for this AOSP project.
2. Can I use these configurations for cross-version android build, say if I want to compile version 6.x, can 5.x configs can be used. (Manufacturer will take several months to release version update) or Create new configurations using some guide/tutorial/book or something.

I also followed other similar questions on stack but not able to find a concrete solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Can I use CM or other projects (eg. AICP etc.) device configurations for this AOSP project.

Yes, you can. But this may not be an easy process. Because device configurations may derive from other devices or common configurations (eg, qcom tree), you must merge all of the configurations to your AOSP project.

2. Can I use these configurations for cross-version android build, say if I want to compile version 6.x, can 5.x configs can be used. (Manufacturer will take several months to release version update) or Create new configurations using some guide/tutorial/book or something.

You'd better don't do this. There are lots of vendor proprietary blobs which target to specifitic version, and probably doesn't work for other major versions.